# How to access individual elements within a rolling window on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, window, apply

I have a dataframe with the quarterly U.S. GDP as column values. I would like to look at the values, 3 at a time, and find the index where the GDP fell for the next two consecutive quarters. This means I need to compare individual elements within df['GDP'] with each other, in groups of 3.

Here's an example dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,10), columns=['GDP'])
df

    GDP
0   4
1   4
2   4
3   1
4   4
5   4
6   8
7   2
8   3
9   9
```

I'm using `df.rolling().apply(find_recession)`, but I don't know how I can access individual elements of the rolling window within my `find_recession()` function.

```
gdp['Recession_rolling'] = gdp['GDP'].rolling(window=3).apply(find_recession_start)
```

How can I access individual elements within the rolling window, so I can make a comparison such as gdp_val_2 < gdp_val_1 < gdp_val?

The .rolling().apply() will go through the entire dataframe, 3 values at a time, so let's take a look at one particular window, which starts at index location 6:

```
   GDP
6  8   # <- gdp_val
7  2   # <- gdp_val_1
8  3   # <- gdp_val_2
```

How can I access gdp_val, gdp_val_1, and gdp_val_2 within the current window?

Comment: Your question is unclear. A small sample of your data, and expected result will help a lot. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [The docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html#pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply) say that the function ```Must produce a single value from an ndarray input...```. So you just index *into* it.  I imagine it is the first positional argument passed.  Write a dummy function that prints what it is passed.

Comment: Try ```numpy.all(a[1:] < a[:-1])```  in the function.

Comment: Yes, wwii, it turns out it was just as simple as arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]. I didn't realize that using df.rolling().apply(lambda x: my_function(x)) passes a list of the windowed elements into my_function().

Answer (score 1):

Using a lambda expression within .apply() will pass an array into the custom function (find_recession_start), and so I can just access the elements as I would any list/array e.g. `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,10), columns=['GDP'])

def my_func(arr):
    if((arr[2] < arr[1]) & (arr[1] < arr[0])):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['Result'] = df.rolling(window=3).apply(lambda x: my_func(x))
df

    GDP Result
0   8   NaN
1   0   NaN
2   8   0.0
3   1   0.0
4   9   0.0
5   7   0.0
6   9   0.0
7   8   0.0
8   3   1.0
9   9   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't, but you can use your knowledge about the structure of the dataframe/series.

You know the size of the window, you know the current index - therefore, you can output the shift relative to the current index:

Let's pretend, here is your gdp:

```
In [627]: gdp
Out[627]:
0    8
1    0
2    0
3    4
4    0
5    3
6    6
7    2
8    5
9    5
dtype: int64
```

The naive approach is just to return the `(argmin() - 2)` and add it to the current index:

```
In [630]: gdp.rolling(window=3).apply(lambda win: win.argmin() - 2) + gdp.index
Out[630]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    4.0
6    4.0
7    7.0
8    7.0
9    7.0
dtype: float64
```

The naive approach won't return the correct result, since you can't predict which index it would return when there are equal values, and when there is a rise in the middle. But you understand the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That is not quite what I'm looking for. I need to know how to access individual elements of the win array within a custom defined function. so if I have gdp.rolling(window=3).apply(lambda win: find_recession_start(win)), how can I access the elements of win within find_recession_start()?

Comment: @Codedorf: win[0], win[1], win[2]?

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. With new *pandas* versions instead of `arr[0], arr[1]`... etc, you have to write `arr.iloc[0], arr.iloc[1]`... etc.